# How to build a WPF app so everyone can install and use it

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, asp.net-core, desktop-application

I am entangled in how to work so that after I finish building the wpf app, I can give it to another computer by downloading the app (for example, downloading the .exe file). I also tried it, but when I ran the .exe file, it only showed a popup cmd and then disappeared. Then I have pulish with self-contanied deployment mode. Here is an image of the following files when I published at bin\release:
[Path: C:\Users\ASUS\Source\Repos\UserService\WpfApp1\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\publish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut3u5.png)

If I run the .exe file in a folder then run normally. But when I copy it to a deskop and run it is still the same (can't run).
I want to ask how can I help my app to be used by other computers. Thank you mn! Forget more, my app is using .net core 3.0 already.

Comment: There is a useful article that I often use here: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/3-ways-to-deploy-a-winforms-or-wpf-net-core-application it can depend on whether you are using just .NET or .NET Core, a useful method I use to test is the new 'Sandbox' feature built into the latest Win10 update, which starts a fresh computer in a VM really easily for you. I copy my published apps into that sandbox to test.

Comment: Thank u. But Window Sandbox require Win10 Pro(or Enterprise). My laptop uses Win10 Home :((. I wanna test with a app too. Do u have any suggestion?

Comment: Ah, you are correct, I didn't even notice as I have Pro. You could use alternative free software such as Oracle VirtualBox https://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: Maybe check out this blogpost: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingATinyNETCore30EntirelySelfcontainedSingleExecutable.aspx

Comment: Anyway, thank you all. I solved when this blog @JG3 suggested me.